# If statement based on scroll position not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need the nav bar to be white when scrolling over the blue section only. I have tried to do this myself but it doesn't work properly. This is not the end result I am trying to achieve I just need this to work so that I can continue coding it. thanks

https://codepen.io/Reece_Dev/pen/MmKprq

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
  var page1Top = $("#sec_one").scrollTop();
  var page1Bot = $("#sec_one").outerHeight();

  var page2 = $("#sec_two").scrollTop();
  var page3 = $("#sec_three").scrollTop();

  if (scrollPos => page1Top && scrollPos < page1Bot) {
    $('nav').css("background-color", "#ffffff");
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

nav ul {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul li a {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a {}

.sections {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#sec_one {
  background-color: blue;
}

#sec_two {
  background-color: red;
}

#sec_three {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" id="link 1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" id="link 2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="" id="link 3">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="sec_one" class="sections">

</div>

<div id="sec_two" class="sections">

</div>

<div id="sec_three" class="sections">

</div>
```

Comment: `=>` is an arrow function in javaScript, use `>=` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because "superior or equal" needs to be written this way in JavaScript: `>=`. Yours is like this: `=>`.

And you need to change back the color if the scroll position condition is false:

```
if(scrollPos >= page1Top && scrollPos < page1Bot){
    $('nav').css("background-color", "#ffffff");
} else {
    $('nav').css("background-color", "#000000");
}
```

If the blue section is the first one at the top of the page, you should define it to white in the CSS code.

See working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hulothe/2de4aj1d/).